# Make text italic without "-Italic" font file in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, fonts

**How can I make the text Italic if the custom font that I use only has -Regular font?**

I use this extension to make it italic but it crashes in fontDescriptor part:

```
func withTraits(traits:UIFontDescriptor.SymbolicTraits) -> UIFont {
    let descriptor = fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(traits)
    return UIFont(descriptor: descriptor!, size: 0) 
}

func bold() -> UIFont {
    return withTraits(traits: .traitBold) }

func italic() -> UIFont {
    return withTraits(traits: .traitItalic) }
```

Usage:

```
let s = UIFont(name:"Archivo Black", size: 20.0).italic()
print("Output: ", s)
```

Tools:

- Device ver: iOS 12.3.1
- Xcode ver: 10.2.1
- macOS: 10.14.5

Answer (score 0):

```
let descriptor = fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(traits)
```

The above line returns an **optional** font descriptor which means it doesn't exist for all fonts.

I think you need to have corresponding font style (**italic**) installed on your machine for font-family **Archivo Black**. Download and install **.ttf** file for the italic variant of the Archivo Black font.

You can use something like this to avoid the crash.

```
extension UIFont {
    func withTraits(traits: UIFontDescriptor.SymbolicTraits) -> UIFont {
        if let descriptor = fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(traits) {
            // Initialize a new instance of UIFont with desired symbolic trait if exists
            return UIFont(descriptor: descriptor, size: self.pointSize)
        }
        // Fall back to default version of the font
        return self
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Sarath, the thing is Archivo Black doesn't have italic font file. So I'm hoping to use the build-in italic style for text in swift. But using the code above doesn't help me :(

Comment: Hi @PepengHapon. As far as I know, you can't use the italic variant of a font unless there's an italic variant installed on your system. For example, you have an italic variant (Avenir-Oblique) for font **Avenir** but you don't have one for **American Typewriter**.

Answer (score -1):

In storyboard select the textview or label and change its type from plain to attributed and select the text and left click on it select the font and under font you will found italic. You can see it in this picture 
[image]

Comment: Hi @Munzareen, I am using a custom font. And I'm adding the font name from the return of API programmatically just like my code. So any customization in storyboard will be disregarded when app loads.